# Codeigniter imagens nao carrega

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sou novo utilizando o CI, e estou tendo problemas com ele pois ele não carrega as imagens em ambiente *localhost (usando XAMPP)*. Já inspecionei e verifiquei se o caminho esta tudo ok, e esta de fato, mas nada da imagem carregar.

Já testei em *localhost*, mas sem utilizar o CI e a imagem carrega normalmente, gostaria que alguém com mais conhecimentos que eu me ajudasse.

```
<div id="products">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo form_open("shop/add"); ?>
                    <div class="name"><?php echo $product->name; ?></div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <?php echo img(array(
                            'src' => 'img/'.$product->image,
                            'class' => 'thumb',
                            'alt' => $product->name)); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price">$<?php echo $product->price; ?></div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/carrinho/';
```

Comment: vc está usando algum helper ou a tag img direto? se tiver o código fonte edite a pergunta e adicione ele. O `base_url` está configurado como?

Comment: O html gerado pelo `img()` vem como?

Comment: <img src="http://localhost/carrinho/img/rubbar.jpg" class="thumb" alt="Rubbar">

Comment: tem um *http://* antes do localhost

Comment: helpers utlizados - form, html, url

Comment: Tentar mudar o `base_url` apenas para o nome do projeto, acredito que assim ele deve acessar o `assets/img`

Comment: coloquei $config['base_url'] = 'carrinho/'; e nada :/

Answer (score -1):

O problema era que a pasta images estava dentro de Application, coloquei um nivel fora e Funcionou! problema resolvido.

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79775)

Comment: Problema resolvido galera!!

Comment: o problema era que a pasta images estava dentro de Application, coloquei um nivel fora e FUNCIONOU!! as que pelo menos tentaram me ajudar obrigado e sucesso!